# Problema localizando múltiples coincidencias dentro de un listado

Tags: javascript, regex

Saludos chicos, soy algo nuevo este mundo de las expresiones regulares y hago lo posible por estudiarlas.

Hace poco estaba intentando armar un regex que hiciera match con la extensión de un archivo, el cual fue el siguiente (en el ejemplo estoy utilizando la sintaxis para javascript)

```
/\.[^\.]+$/m
```

Y a primera vista, funciona correctamente, no tengo problemas localizando la extensión de un archivo desde un texto plano. No obstante, el problema comienza cuando le entrego un listado de nombres de archivos, pues sólo se queda con el primer match, y de allí no sigue.

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/l6txhR/1

¿En qué estoy fallando? Agradezco las sugerencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agregale el modificador `g` al final de la expresion:

```
/\.[^\.]+$/mg
```

El modificador `g` se utiliza cuando se quiere todos los matches de la expresion:

```js
function leerExtensiones()
{
  var value = document.querySelector("textarea").value;
 var matches = value.match(/\.[^\.]+$/mg);
 console.log(matches);
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="leerExtensiones()">Leer extensiones</button>
```

[Ejemplo actualizado](https://regex101.com/r/l6txhR/2).